# How to pass a dynamic variable?

Tags: php

Did My research on this,Couldn't find what i was looking for.

```
class headerStyle{
 // now  creating our CONSTRUCTOR function
 function __construct($args=array()) {
     $this->fields = array('background','color','fontSize','backgroundUrl','imagePosition','Width','Height','backgroundSize','margin','padding','backgroundRepeat');
      foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
                $this->{"$field"} = $args["$field"];
                 }
         }
}


$style = new headerStyle(
       array(
         background =>"#DEDEDC",
         color=>"#F5F3F4",
         fontSize=>"24px",
         backgroundUrl=>"_images/bodyBg1.jpg",
         backgroundSize=>"50% 50%",
         padding=>"10px 0px 0px 0px",
         margin=>"0px 0px 0px 0px",
         width=>"100%",
         height=>"60px",
         imagePosition=>"top-left",
            )
);
```

instead of giving a value i need to pass a dynamic variable like background=>$_post['headerBg'];

Comment: And what is preventing you?

Comment: `array('background' => $_POST['headerBg'])` - Works perfectly fine if `$_POST['headerBg']` exists.

Comment: sorry,$headerbg=$_POST['headerBg'];I need to pass the $headerbg instead of value

Comment: What? Please clarify the question with as many examples and words as possible, it's really unclear what you want.

Comment: And quote your array indices! It's `array('background' => ...)`, not `array(background => ...)`. Try turning on error reporting and you'll see a lot of things going wrong. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. The POST array in PHP can be accessed with `$_POST['headerBg'];` (notice it's uppercase).

```
class headerStyle{
 // now  creating our CONSTRUCTOR function
 function __construct($args=array()) {
     $this->fields = array('background','color','fontSize','backgroundUrl','imagePosition','Width','Height','backgroundSize','margin','padding','backgroundRepeat');
      foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
                $this->{"$field"} = $args["$field"];
                 }
         }
}


$style = new headerStyle(
       array(
         background =>$_POST['headerBg'],
         color=>"#F5F3F4",
         fontSize=>"24px",
         backgroundUrl=>"_images/bodyBg1.jpg",
         backgroundSize=>"50% 50%",
         padding=>"10px 0px 0px 0px",
         margin=>"0px 0px 0px 0px",
         width=>"100%",
         height=>"60px",
         imagePosition=>"top-left",
            )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array setup is wrong, it has numerical keys, you want an associative array. Define the defaults and then use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to overwrite defaults with any elements that are set:

```
function __construct($args=array()) {
     $defaults = array('background' => '', 'color' => '', 'fontSize' => '', 'backgroundUrl' => '', 'imagePosition' => '', 'Width' => '', 'Height' => '', 'backgroundSize' => '', 'margin' => '', 'padding' => '', 'backgroundRepeat' => '');

     $this->fields = array_merge($defaults, $args);
}
```

It can be used as you tried, either by hardcoding the elements, or get from `$_POST`:

```
$style = new headerStyle(
   array(
     background =>'',
     color=>"#F5F3F4",
     fontSize=>"24px")
);
```